# How to delete set of entities by id list?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm

How can i do something like this

```
Session
.CreateQuery("delete from People where People.Id in (:idList)")
.SetParameter("idList", idList)
.ExecuteUpdate()
```

but without HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no Fluent Nhibernate syntax for deleting entities. I also used HQL (or even SQL) when I wanted to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
foreach(var item in idList)
{
    Session.Delete(Session.Load<People>(item));
}
```

and to improve performance of this set batch size to 20 like this in configurations:

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">20</property>
```

this behavior existing by default in Nhibernate 3.2

Comment: If i not mistaken this approach generates query for every item but in single batch? But how to do this with single query?

Comment: And you should use Session.Load instead of Session.Get. Then you won't have a lot of Selects before deleting each item

Comment: @k0lpak: I think you can not proceed in single query.

Comment: @Sly: Get or load will generate selects in delete you can profile it and see results.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this will batch the delete statements? As far as I can remember NHProf shows the app sending n+1 DELETE statements to sql server compared to batching INSERT statements using this technique where NHProf shows you sending them in single query.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=951669&) that might do what you need. It is one of the overloads of session.Delete